# ImageView is NOT SHOWING in a linear layout (android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view

I'm creating an android application and got into issues already in the first stage.

I'm trying to display an image with an ImageView inside a Layout.

My code is as follows:

activity_starter.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StarterActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/starterPic"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.84"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and StarterActivity.java:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starter);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Entered Starter Screen");

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.starterPic); 
        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        mImageView.invalidate();
}
```

The issues are:

1. I can't hide the title bar on the top (black bar says "WhereIsIt" (app. name)).
2. The image in the imageview is not shown.

I've been digging into this for hours, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do u call mImageView.invalidate();?

Comment: it doesn't show without it, as well

Answer (score 1):

To hide the `Title bar` , you just need put this code in your `onCreate` method :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //add this line 
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_starter);
             // rest of your code 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

About hiding the `titlebar`, you just need to set this theme on your Activity, in the manifest.xml.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

And the action bar disappears.

I run your code (only the xml layout)and the image shows, but I used other values for the padding.
Check if the values you are using for padding are not the responsible for this issue.

**Edit**:

Use this code to see the actual size of your image:

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
           int finalHeight = mImageView.getMeasuredHeight();
           int finalWidth = mImageView.getMeasuredWidth();
           System.out.println("Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: In fact, now that I've set the theme you gave me in the menifest file, instead of getting blank white view, I get blank black view. So now I need two fixes - to get the image appearing, and the background color get back to white ;)

Comment: @ user1067083 use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
instead :D

Comment: haha...alright now I'm back to white blank view...any new hints with that image?

Comment: Don't make any changes to your image inside your onCreate(). try to set the image as background of the LinearLayout and see if it appears. also, try to use match_parent on both layout_width and layout_height and remove layout_weight.

Comment: Still the same. Though I tell you what I've noticed - if I log the imageview's getHeight(), for instance, after the code in onCreate, I get 0. you think it means something?

Comment: Did you try to remove your padding values?

Comment: about your code....the system print doesn't even work. I think the image is not drawn at all

Answer (score 0):

You can hide action bar by

```
 getActionBar().hide(); //if API >=11
```

or

```
 getSupportActionBar().hide(): //if API <11
```

Also, I don't see any issue with your layout. I could see the image in my nexus 5.

Comment: That's strange...I can't see it in my galaxy s3, and it doesn't have much of a differnce regarding screen size

Comment: try removing mImageView.invalidate();

Comment: It works fine in S4 too :) Try removing the layout_weight and change layout_width="wrap_content".

Comment: don't make any code in onCreate .. just do only setContentView with all the above changes i suggested.

Comment: same crap :(. Thanks for all the attempts

Comment: can u share the complete code what you do in Activity. Are you doing any stuff in activity onStart()/onResume() ?

Comment: try this on yout ImageView xml
android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: a) what I've put in my question is, for now, my complete code. and b) I did fitXY as you told me and it still now showing anything

Comment: How does it not work?
Then replace the system.print by Log.i("values", "Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);

And make your ImageView final.

Answer (score 0):

```
 In manifest file just add the bold line for hiding titlebar
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"** >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.abc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
and for Image just use this code in xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/starterPic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
and this code in java
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.starterPic); 
mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have forgot to set the orientation of the `LinearLayout`.
Try adding this to the xml within `<LinearLayout >`:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```